# How can I enable epel-release before installing packages with cloud-init?

Tags: centos, centos7, cloud-init, yaml, centos8

I'm trying to install a few packages on CentOS 8 via `cloud-init`, like this:

```
package_upgrade: true

packages:
  - firewalld
  - htop
```

One of them one of them requires `epel-release` repo to be installed first:

```
No match for argument: htop
2019-10-21 15:50:35,444 - util.py[WARNING]: Failed to install packages: ['firewalld', 'htop']
```

How can I install `epel-release` first and then install packages?

Comment: Have you tried adding `epel-release` to packages?
Or you can probably just add it as `yum_repos` in cloud-init?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your cloud init script:

```
yum_repos:
    epel-release:
        baseurl: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/7/$basearch
        enabled: true
        failovermethod: priority
        gpgcheck: true
        gpgkey: http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-7
        name: Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - Release
```

Comment: This is for Centos 7...